# how to call the function for export (node.js / sequelize)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

how to call the function (search_all_user) for export (node.js / sequelize)

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, Sequelize, DataTypes) {
var User = sequelize.define('user', {

    id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, unique: true, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    username: {type: Sequelize.STRING(32), unique: true, allowNull: false},

}, {
    classMethods: {
        search_all_user: function() {
            User.findOne({where: {username: 'coderock'}}).then(function(user){
               console.log(user.username);
            });
        }
    }
});

return User;
};
```

**controller:**

```
model  = require('./../models/user.js');

exports.index = function (request, response, next) {
// how to insert function () search_all_user?
response.render('user_signup', {title: 'Регистрация пользователя'});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`search_all_users` defined in class methods of user model. so you can call it with in your controller after requiring your model. here is an example :

```
 var model  = require('./../models/user.js');

exports.index = function (request, response, next) {
model.search_all_users.then(...);
};
```